# JPA subquery for self join table

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

Please help me to write JPA query for below DB subquery

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT es WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM EVENT e WHERE e.id = es.id  and es.series.id is not null )
```

Event self joined with event and find out all events with series id null

Comment: Can you describe it more like is query running or nor ?If query is running on mysql query browser then use native query insaid of jpa query.

Comment: Most of queries are written in JPA so we tried to use it

Comment: Ok,what is issue you faced as JPA query with this query.